# simulate unable to open database error in iphone dev 5.0

Tags: ios, sqlite

Hi i have a requirement to simulate an error that states the iphone applicatio is unable to open the database and display values from it. i use sqllite. Please let me know how to simulate that error. I tried by locking the database file, changing the db file to readonly, but nothing happened... please let me know how to simulate the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the database with a separate connection, set exclusive [locking mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode), and make some change (you don't need to commit it).